# What are the technical steps to upgrade Magento ver. 2.3.4 to Latest Magento ver.2.4.0?

Tags: magento2, upgrade, magento-upgrade

I am trying to upgrade store from `Magento ver. 2.3.4 to Latest Magento ver.2.4.0`
Can anybody advise me what are the ideal steps to upgrade ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do the upgrade in this way :

```
1. create development server from the live site.
2. Upgrade the development website.
3. Do the bug solve and testing. and check everything is working fine.
4. Then you can move the only files from development server to live server.
5. Run the deploy and upgrade, caching and indexing command and check.
```

Here is the technical command to upgrade the magento :

1. Backup the composer.json file.

   ```
   cp composer.json composer.json.bak
   ```
2. Add or remove specific packages based on your needs.

   ```
   composer remove magento/product-community-edition --no-update
   ```
3. Indicate the Magento packages, both the edition and the version that you want to upgrade to.

   ```
   composer require magento/product-community-edition=2.3.5 --no-update
   composer update
   ```

Comment: Thankyou very much Dhiren sir, this is helpful. Can you please add the technical commands/way to do so ? like( db backup or upgrade through cli). whichever is the best practice.

Comment: actual upgrade have 2 way. you can do it by command or manually file replace as well.

Comment: Also can you please elaborate which files you are talking about in point no. 4 ?

Comment: Exactly, the ideal practice says to Update Magento 2 with composer. Correct me if i am wrong.

Comment: Please check the command to upgrade magento.

Comment: Thankyou very much, Let me execute & check

Comment: Step 2 is not necessary i guess.